# NServiceBus impersonation issue after upgrading from 2.6 to 3.0

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I've just upgraded from NSB 2.6 to 3.0 and I'm having an issue with NSB throwing an ArgumentNullException when raising transport message:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport [(null)] <(null)> - 
Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=21d502f4-0e66-4d1e-801c10ddc1cbe40a\34416
        System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: name
           at System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity..ctor(String name)
           at NServiceBus.Impersonation.ImpersonationManager.Transport_TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
           at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
           at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)
```

The scenario is a web app that sends a message to an endpoint currently hosted in a console (but will run as a Windows Service).

The configuration for the web app:

```
Configure.WithWeb()
    .Log4Net()
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()                                    
    .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(false)
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .UnicastBus()
        .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .CreateBus()
    .Start();
```

The endpoint uses the Production profile and has following configuration:

```
   Configure.With()
        .StructureMapBuilder()
        .Sagas()
        .RunTimeoutManager()
        .UnicastBus()
           .ImpersonateSender(false)
```

As you can see, Impersonation is turned off both in the web app as well as in the endpoint (Prior to upgrading I didn't configure Impersonation on the endpoint), but still NSB is trying to impersonate, and failing at it because the WinIdName is null in the message header.

The issue is, why is NSB trying to impersonate when it is configured not to do so, and what has changed since 2.6 causing this to suddenly fail?

**EDIT:** As I investigate further, it looks like it tries to impersonate the user of the web app when sending the message to the endpoint even though it is configured not to do so.

Comment: I think it migt be a bug. Sounds like the same issue as this guy?http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/13140

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. Any idea on when you can have a fix for it?

Comment: Are you using any of the builtin roles? (As_aServer) If so try to remove it and see if it helps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2 issues. One is that we blow up if the identity is null for some reason.

This is now fixed (will be rolled out in NSB 3.0.1)

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/eaaafecbbedc7c82d996ce466434038d70bc27cd

The other is that the role As_aServer overrides the ImpersonateSender(false). This is a bigger change. The workaround is to not use the role and just configure the same settings manually:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/hosting/NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows/Roles/Handlers/ServerRoleHandler.cs